# Helpless with EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I have a result set produced by this query, off data imported into a SqlCe database from CSV:

```
Dim recs = MonitorContext.DataRecords. _
    Where(Function(dr) dr.INDEX >= If(startIndex, dr.INDEX) And dr.INDEX < If(endIndex, dr.INDEX)). _
    Where(Function(dr) dr.TIMESTAMP >= If(startTime, dr.TIMESTAMP) And dr.TIMESTAMP < lastTime)
```

Any attempt at all to enumerate the `recs`, even calling `Count()`, results in an `EntityCommandExecutionException`, with the message "An overflow occurred while converting to datetime." It has an HResult of -2146232004

How can EFCe not read a `DateTime` itself stored in the database? I used EF for the import and all was well.

I am at my wits end, because there is no way I can examine the data. I thought a single step `for` loop might help, but I can't get `Count`.

**ASIDE - Inner exception info:**
HResult: -2147467259
Native error: 25933

Comment: Hi Brady, what are the values of startTime and lastTime?

Comment: @ErikEJ, you hit it. If no value for `lastTime` was passed in, it remained a new-born `DateTime`, of just "12:00:00". Not much is before that, but I don't understand the error anyway.

Comment: Sql datetime starts at year 1755, .NET datetime starts at year 1, Thus the overflow.. (or more like underflow)